# Post from another domain causes session null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

We have a payment sub-system which goes like this;

- User enters payment data
- Payment data sent to the 3rd party service url (with form post / eg. **POST** https://3rdparty.com/form )
- 3rd party service checks data and sends some other data (again using form post but this time to our url / eg **POST** http://localhost/Success)

In other words;

```
http://localhost/Page1 -> POST https://3rdparty.com/Service -> POST http://localhost/Success
```

But when second redirection (3rd party service posting data to our side), session object becomes null.

I've mimicked the **POST** scenario to http://localhost/Success from both **same origin** and **other origin**.

When posting from the same origin

```
http://localhost/Test -> POST -> http://localhost/Success  => OK. Session IS NOT null
```

But when posting from another origin

```
http://testdomain/Test -> POST -> http://localhost/Success  => OK. Session IS null
```

BTW; this happens regardless of other origin's procotol, be it **http** or **https**

What is the source of this behaviour ? I couldn't find anything meaningful...

## EDIT :

I've added the code of the ActionFilterAttribute which intercepts every request and checks for session (due to @mxmissile 's comment)

```
public class LoginFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session[Constants.SessionNames.USER_OBJECT_NAME] == null) 
// this is where I check the Session object and it's null
// it doesn't have any key in it
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Login/Login");

            }

        }
    }
```

## EDIT 2 :

Using the configuration below, which re-writes Set-Cookie header's flags, I was able to modify flags. (suggested at https://blog.elmah.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-secure-cookies-with-web-config-in-net);

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <clear />
      <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=lax" />
      </rule>
      <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="No SameSite">
          <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
          <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=lax" negate="true" />
        </preCondition>
      </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
```

But `SameSite=Lax` wasn't sending cookies to the 3rd party service as stated here https://www.thinktecture.com/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/ , due to Chrome's 80.x updates

So I've changed `SameSite=lax` to `SameSite=none` and **it worked**.

But as I imagine, this would generate new issues with security. Such as **CSRF** attacks.

What would be the best way to do it ?

Comment: There is a cookie for asp.net session tracking which contains the session identifier. Check this asp.net session cookie flag `SameSite` in the browser, is it set to either LAX or Strict? LAX means the cookie will only be sent to the server if the cross site request was executed using GET. Strict means it never will be sent to the server on a cross site request.

Comment: How and Where are you determining the `Session` is null?

Comment: @lgor How can I check flag `SameSite`. I've applied rule below this page https://blog.elmah.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-secure-cookies-with-web-config-in-net/ , but it didn't work.  @mxmissile I've got a `ActionFilterAttribute` on the Success controller. There `ActionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Session` is null

Comment: Post your Filter Attribute's code.

Comment: I've posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you've got the `SameSite=None; Secure` working and just point out a few things that might be of use.

#### What is the source of this behaviour?

The [Chromuim SameSite](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site) [FAQ page](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/faq) has quite good summary of what the change is:

> Q: What are the new SameSite changes?
>
> > Chrome is changing the default behavior for how cookies will be sent in first and third party contexts.

#### as I imagine, this would generate new issues with security.

Based on my interpretation of the quote above, I don't believe so: Chrome will send **less** cookies by default now. By reverting to sending these cookies, you are not increasing your attack surface - you merely restoring your existing flow.
Actually, if you read that page further, there's one thing that is now required - for the cookies to be sent over `HTTPS`. So you are actually better off by acknowledging the fact that these cookies are sensitive and requiring the user to always opt for secure connections.

#### Such as CSRF attacks.

I don't believe this point depends on Chrome Cookie policy. It still is valid. If not doing that already - check out the [Microsoft docsumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks) and see if a standard Razor Html helper will be feasible option for you:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

#### What would be the best way to do it?

Looking at how Google is pushing it as the default behaviour, it seems your best bet is to adopt it I'm afraid.